# How do I build a Cordova 8.x cordova.jar to include in existing Android app?

Tags: android, cordova

I this documentation:

[Cordova documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/webview.html)

I cloned the latest Cordova here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-android

But when I run "ant jar" as described in the documentation, I get this error:

> cordova-android-master/framework/build.xml:124: Cannot find
>   /Users/neigaard/Library/Android/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml imported from
>   /Users/me/cordova-android-master/framework/build.xml

Google say that is because `ant/build.xml` was removed from Android SDK. I found a post saying that I should download a old Android SDK tools and replace my SDK tools folder with that, but I rely on my Android SDK to be working and up to date.

Is there no way to build the Cordova Android jar without an outdated Android SDK or is there somewhere I can download a pre-built jar or is there another way to integrate Cordova into a existing Android app?

Comment: Which android SDK version you are using?

Comment: @Neigaard As per the cordova android 7.0.0 release (https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2017/12/04/cordova-android-7.0.0.html), ant builds are officially deprecated and not supported anymore. So you may have to use gradle instead. Any tweaks to build using ant will be a workaround.

Comment: The easiest way to do that is: Create Cordova app and move all your java sources there. It will take you around 1 hour instead to integrate Cordova into existing Android app. Every time you could fail on other pitfall

Answer (score 4):

You don't really need the .jar anymore, Cordova is distributed through gradle, so you can just add this in the dependencies section of your app gradle file:

`implementation 'org.apache.cordova:framework:7.1.0'`

Comment: Just for info, it needs to use `jcenter()` as repository

Comment: Version 10 and newer are in mavenCentral, no need for jcenter anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Tutorial [cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/)… looks outdated. If you just want to embed a cordova webview you don't really need the .jar anymore, **Cordova is distributed through gradle, so you can just add this in the dependencies section of your app gradle file:**

```
implementation 'org.apache.cordova:framework:7.1.0'
```

**However** if you want to create jar through ant then you don't required to use complete outdated Android SDK.You have to just place **ant/build.xml** in tools folder.
Below are the steps to create corodva.x.x.x.jar on Windows

**Step-1** Download Android tool package from below location:
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-windows.zip

**Step-2** Copy ant folder to
*C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools*

**Step-3** Install Cordova using npm

```
npm install -g cordova
```

You can install specific version of cordova using cordova@version.

**Step-4** Go to below location and copy your local.properties from your android project:
*C:\Users\xxxxx\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\x.x.xx\package\framework*

**Step-5** Navigate to the Android package's /framework directory and run **ant jar**. 
It creates the Cordova .jar file, formed as /framework/cordova-x.x.x.jar

**FYI:** It is recommended to refer the cordova requirements-and-support https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html#requirements-and-support

Comment: Now I get this error: "build.xml:396: Problem: failed to create task or type checkenv". I have googled it and only found something about not having set the correct path to Android SDK, and I have that setup correctly. Any ideas here? Also, I can not find any "npm_cache\cordova-android\x.x.xx\package\framework" anywhere, and I have run "npm install -g cordova" with succes.

Comment: @Neigaard After installation you should have cordova here C:\Users\your_user_id\ **.cordova**

Comment: When i was making jar from source code(i.e. https://github.com/apache/cordova-android) then i was also getting the same error so i tried installation of cordova from npm module and it created successfully.

Comment: How do you create the jar from npm?

Comment: I do not have a .cordova lib in my home dir

Comment: I am on macOS, it seems to have installed here "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova", but there are no "lib" or "frameworks" in there. cordova -version gives me 8.0.0 if that helps

Comment: could you search **ant.properties** in your macbook?you can refer the framework folder if you found?

Comment: The only cordova ant.properties I can find is in the cordova app I created and named test "test/node_modules/cordova-android/framework/ant.properties"

Comment: Same problem, gives "build.xml:396: Problem: failed to create task or type checkenv" error

Comment: In this case instead of ant/build.xml please try to replace the **tool** folder in Android SDK.you can take backup of **tool** folder

Comment: That worked. This is the most crazy build setup I have ever seen, it seems very broken. But I have a jar now, thank you :)

Comment: hehe no problem.@Neigaard-Please voteup my answer if found usefull.

Comment: It did not work.. It builds a cordova-7.0.0.jar even though cordova -version gives me 8.0.0, and the jar is 126kb and basicly is empty and useless :(

Comment: There is a **VERSION** file parallel to framework folder. It gets from there.I also checked in gitsource code(https://github.com/apache/cordova-android) it is **7.2.0-dev**

Comment: Yes mine to in the git version, still the resulting jar is useless because it contains nothing

Comment: How you can say that jar is not correct? Jar is correct if it contains **engine** subpackage and **31 base classes/Interface**. However tutorial https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/webview.html looks outdated. If you just want to embed a cordova webview you don't really need the .jar anymore, you can follow this one http://docs.phonegap.com/develop/1-embed-webview/android/

Comment: The size og 125kb is a hint, but if I rename it to .zip and unzip it I get a .zip.cpgz and if I unpack that I get a .zip and so on, AFAIK that is a clear sign that the created .jar file is corrupt

Comment: It is the jar file that is corrupt, so I will never even get a .class file. A jar file is simply a zip file

Comment: @Neigaard- these are the screenshot of my machine:

https://imgur.com/vFkxpkj     

https://imgur.com/i9WgVEr

can you share you generated jar?